# best way to monitor web app performance in tomcat

Tags: java, performance-monitoring, tomcat6

I have a web application running in Tomcat 6.x on a Debian Linux box.

I have recently started using Google App Engine for another java app and now have serious stats envy; is there a comparable tool out there for monitoring my tomcat app's performance? The three statistics I would love to see are:

- Requests per second over the course of the week

  Average response (latency) time per URL

  Total memory usage over the course of the week

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need a mix of tools.

The response times taken and hits counts would be analyzed from the access log file by a tool like 
[AwStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) which is a quite popular choice.

For the memory usage and other stuff like CPU etc, you could install either LambdaProbe or it's fork [PSIProbe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) which will give you details such as this.

Both are open source products and usage is very similar to the Tomcat Manager.

Answer (score 1):

check out moskito:
http://moskito.anotheria.net/moskitodemo/mui/

regards
Leon